# Python/pip failed installing Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I have Python 3.8 installed, I was able to install numpy and scipy flawlessly. When I try to install matplotlib I get this output in my command prompt.

```
    building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -IC:\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python38\include -IC:\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/checkdep_freetype2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/checkdep_freetype2.obj
    checkdep_freetype2.c
    src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\duket\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6otudvqg\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\duket\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6otudvqg\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\duket\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2fr17_ng\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have no idea how to fix this, I've updated pip and I have also tried to install from a .whl file but still no dice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If you want the full command prompt output I made a pastebin with it here: https://pastebin.com/HNXcGrDH

Comment: No current matplotlib version supports python 3.8. You will need to use python 3.7 to be able to use matplotlib. Or you can wait for the next matplotlib release that will hopefully support python 3.8 as well.

Comment: If I install python 3.7, wouldn't I have to install the 3.7 versions of numpy/scipy ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Versions of those libraries need to match.

Answer (score 1):

Download the prebuilt lib from Prof. Gohlke and install using pip

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib

```
pip install matplotlib-3.1.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `freetype` library that is a dependecy of `matplotlib` Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild) for building the required libraries for `matplotlib`. Note however that the latest release of `matplotlib` does only support `python 3.7`. You might still be able to build from source if you use the latest version [from github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib), but there is no guarantee for its stability, esspecially since there are currently no [official tests of matplotlib for python 3.8](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15404)