# matlibplot real-time plotting doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created the script below for real-time data plotting. But the plot which shows up is empty. Could you tell me what's the case?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from itertools import count
import random

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
axl = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()

def animate(i):

    x_vals.append(next(index))
    y_vals.append(random.randint(0, 5))

    axl.clear()
    axl.plot(x_vals,y_vals)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

I'm using python 3.8, matlibplot 3.1.2 and PyCharm as IDE.

Comment: last time I checked, matplotlib wasn't fully compatible with python 3.8. Try python 3.7...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386191/python-pip-failed-installing-matplotlib

Comment: If there is a figure coming out, it means matplotlib is correctly installed, so it's not a python 3.8 issue. I suppose you have a problem with pycharm, because the code itself works fine. Did you try running this from the console without pycharm in the game?